# Should I use getters and setters inside a class implementation?

Tags: java

Or it depends?

For example fictional class:

```
public class Worker {

    private boolean paused;

    public boolean isPaused() {
        return paused;
    }

    public void onIteration() {
        if (!paused) {
            doIteration();
        }
    }

}
```

Or would it be better if I use `if isPaused() { }` in the example above ?

Is there any rule about what I always must use?

Comment: You can use both ways, but you should use `isPaused`, if it's doing some extra-job (other than just returning paused).

Comment: Since Worker can be subclassed, and isPaused overridden, maybe better to use isPaused(), unless overriding this functionality would be wrong, in which case you should make isPaused final

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the *getter* since it decides the internal logic. In your case there's no much logic, you simply return the value.

But consider a situation where `isPaused` will be changed to:

```
public boolean isPaused() {
   return isReallyPaused(paused);
}
```

Another reason I prefer to use *getters*,

If it was an `int`, I wouldn't take chance of changing it by mistake, and instead of writing `if(myInt == 5)` (that can be `=` by mistake), I would use `if(getMyInt() == 5)`.

Answer (score 1):

Well as a rule always use getters.
why ?

Lets say you made it a public member and after 5 usages of this class you decide that now you need to add more logic in to this.

Now its paused only if A and B.
Maybe the user does not have permission to view if isPauesd true or false.

How do you change this without breaking the outer usages of the class ?

You cant, but if you use a getter then its not problem:

```
public boolean isPaused() {
    if (hasPermissions){
       return isPaused;
    }

    throw newPermissionException();
}
```

I changed the code with out breaking the usages.
In fact the users of this class don't even know of the change.

This is called encapsulation.

Comment: _Lets say you made it a public_  +  _This is called encapsulation._  -  But I wrote about using **inside** a class **implementation**, **not outside**.